# How to import python functions from different file (in Ubuntu)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have a python file called `hero.py` that refers to other python files located in `views.py` (Both these files exist in the same folder).

`hero.py` code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from .views import main, returnSum, most_frequent, find_mine_site_view_id, get_user_Activity, initialise_analytics_reporting

list_of_mines = ['mine1', 'mine2', 'mine3']

start_date = 'yesterday'
end_date = 'yesterday'

main(list_of_mines, start_date, end_date)
```

After making the file executable with `chmod +x hero.py` and adding  `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the top of `hero.py`, I get this error when running `./hero.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hero.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import main, returnSum, most_frequent, find_mine_site_view_id, get_user_Activity, initialise_analytics_reporting
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.views'; '__main__' is not a package
```

I am aware that my views.py is not a package, I simply want to import the functions that exist within `views.py`

Not sure if it is an Ubuntu thing.

Please help

When running `ls -la` in the folder where both files exist:

```
total 72
drwxrwxr-x 8 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May 13 06:39 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May 11 19:19 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May  7 08:52 .idea
-rw-rw-r-- 1 llewellyn llewellyn     0 May  7 07:21 __init__.py
drwxrwxr-x 2 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May 13 06:18 __pycache__
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn    86 May 12 17:39 admin.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn   108 May 12 17:40 apps.py
drwxrwxr-x 3 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May  7 09:04 config
drwxrwxr-x 3 llewellyn llewellyn  4096 May  9 11:34 migrations
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn  2607 May 12 17:40 models.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 llewellyn llewellyn 16146 May 13 06:17 views.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the dot before views:

```
from views import main, returnSum, most_frequent, ...
#    ^ here
```

**Edit:**
**To import from subfolder:**
Use `.` as separator:
When file is located like this:

```
someFolder
+-main.py <- file with import
`-the
   `-path
     `-to
       `-module.py <- in this file is func1
```

do:

```
from the.path.to.module import func1
# imports func1 from file module.py
# then use like:
func1()
```

or

```
from the.path.to import module
# imports whole module
# then use like:
module.func1()
```

or

```
import the.path.to.module
# use:
the.path.to.module.func1()
```

or

```
import the.path.to.module as mod
#imports the.path.to.module that is accessed by identifier mod
#so use it like
mod.func1()
```

You can combine `as` and `from` too:

```
from the.path.to import module as mod
#use:
mod.func1()
```

**When the path is string or file isn't subfolder, you can do this:**
For Python 3.5+

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/the/path/to/module.py")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
# then use like this:
module.func1()
```

For Python 2

```
import imp

module = imp.load_source('module.name', '/the/path/to/module.py')
module.func1()
```

Comment: If I want to import something from a file located in a specific path. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can create  a package from view.py. see here: [link](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

then you can import that package from anywhere in the system

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports only works within a package. When you run a python script within a directory that was supposed to be a package, this directory stops being a package.

If you do not want to create a package, simply put views.py in one of the [module search paths](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), then use absolute import.